# Listing all possible remainders in Z2[x] when dividing by x^2+1

Tags: abstract-algebra

List all possible remainders in Z2[x] when dividing by x^2+ 1.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of context.

Answer (score 2):

They are polynomials of degree $<2$, if $P$ is such a polynomial, $P=0(x^2+1)+P$ they are $0,1,x,x+1$.

Comment: What about $0$?